# Switch Cases's code block doesn't get indented in JavaScript mode

Tags: indentation, javascript, js-mode

I'm having trouble with the indentation of the cases's code-blocks in my switch statements

it looks like this:

```
switch(var)
{
    case "case1":
    case's code line 1;
    case's code line 2;
    break;
    default:
    stuff...
    break;
}
```

I'd really prefer that it looked like this:

```
switch(var)
{
    case "case1":
        case's code line 1;
        case's code line 2;
        break;
    default:
        stuff...
        break;
}
```

it was working properly before, so I took a look at the mode's .el file, but I didn't understand anything so I left it there.

Comment: What is the major mode of the buffer? You can find out with `C-h v major-mode` while your cursor is in that buffer. There are a few possibilities (`js-mode`, `js2-mode`, `js3-mode` and possibly others), so it would be good to know what we are dealing with here.

Comment: It is in js mode: major-mode is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.

Its value is ‘js-mode’
Original value was ‘fundamental-mode’

Answer (score 0):

For `js-mode` I set this:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq js-switch-indent-offset js-indent-level)))
```